# Do Scala 2.8.1 and SBT work ok with JDK 7?

Tags: scala, java, sbt

Aren't Scala 2.8.1 compiler, applications built with it, Sbt 1.7.4/1.7.5RC and Scala 2.7.7 (needed to run Sbt) known to have any problems running with a current alpha of OpenJDK 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are issues, mostly with swing because they took some formerly non-generic types and gave them type parameters.  Scala is not big on this sort of thing.

I ported trunk to a recent version of openjdk here: https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/openjdk

There was one bit I had to disable until I get a compiler fix, which is documented here: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3634

Answer (score 1):

People frequently post benchmark results for Scala using OpenJDK 7 to the mailing list, and backwards compatibility is always a huge, overpowering concern with Java, so I think everything works fine.